# How to strncpy() to WCHAR

Tags: c++, c, unicode, strncpy

I got a piece of code that works under Multi-Byte Character Set. However, I want to convert this piece of code to UNICODE. So I fixed lots of stuff, but failed at the strncpy() line. This is the line that I want to change:

```
strncpy(a.szTip, szToolTip, bLength);
```

I used lots of functions to fix this, but all of them failed.

Here's the error:

```
strncpy cannot convert parameter 1 from WCHAR[128] to char *
```

Comment: strncpy() will copy bytes until it finds a byte with the value 0 (or reaches the specified maximum number of bytes), and then stop copying.  So even if you cast the parameters to force it to compile, it probably wouldn't do what you want -- in particular, any multi-byte character that contained a zero for one of its bytes would cause strncpy() not to copy the remainder of the string.  Perhaps you want to use wstrncpy() instead?

Answer (score 8):

When dealing with wide characters, use [`wcsncpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wcsncpy) (and other relevant functions).

As Remy Lebeau points out, using the `_tcsncpy()` macro is safer if you want to support both ANSI & Unicode builds (it expands to the right function respectively).

Comment: when dealing with Win32 API `TCHAR` values (which `szTip` is), use `_tcsncpy()` or `wsprintf()` instead.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware what `szTip` was. Thanks.